# I need help to fix this code, Can someone say why isnt this working?

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto

Im trying to add pictured menu ,but it gives me error.[Error, .lua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlgXZ.png)

```
function loadPlayerInventory()
    TBCore.Functions.TriggerServerCallback('tb-inventory:server:getPlayerInventory', function(data)
        items = 
        inventory = data.inventory
        weapons = data.weapons
        local weight = 0
        

        if inventory ~= nil then
            for k, v in pairs(inventory) do
                table.insert(items, inventory[k])
                weight = weight + (inventory[k].amount * inventory[k].weight)
            end
```

Comment: It is often preferred that you add error messages as text, additionally a more narrow title is better then "my code is broke" something as simple as just the error string is a sufficient title. One last piece of advise its best to make sure your code posted accurately displays your issue, as piglet points out in their answer your posted code has an addition error

Answer (score 1):

```
items =
```

should give you an error `"unexpected symbol near =` So you should not even get to that point that your callback is called.

You forgot to assign a value to items. Your code suggests that it should be a table.

The error in the screenshot is caused by indexing data, a local nil value.

```
inventory = data.inventory
```

This is because your callback is called but no parameter `data` is given. Find out why or make sure you don't index it if it is nil.

Something like

```
if data then
  inventory = data.inventory
end
```

or

```
inventory = data and data.inventory
```

for example